# How to map single-products to categories in my scenario?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.6, schema

I have the tables depicted in the following diagram:

[image]

Let's say I have only two products in my database at moment, one that has variants, while the other does not have them.

[image]

Now my question is: how do I map my `Product WITHOUT variants` to a `CATEGORIES` in the `PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES_MAPPING` table?

Comment: Could you please [not use screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530)? Please put all your DDL and DML in as text - `SHOW CREATE TABLE...` and `INSERT INTO blah VALUES (...)` Help us to help you!

Answer (score 1):

For simplification, add a "variant" even for products without variants.

Is there any more info on categories other than `cat_name`?  If not, then I suggest it is "over-normalization" to even have the `Categories` table.  Simply put cat_name in `Product_to_Categories_Mapping`.

`Product_to_Categories_Mapping` needs

```
PRIMARY KEY(product_id, category),  -- the _pair_ is unique
INDEX(category, product_id)         -- to go the other direction
```

Comment: Yes there are more columns in CATEGORIES table, I just showed relevent columns in my question

Comment: How about that single product have variants in future? Just delete that EMPTY variant row?